# UIwebview content is not loading properly

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiwebview

I got a pretty weird thing, am using `UIWebView` in one of my apps, but while the device is being rotated to landscape mode, the `UIWebView` content is not loading properly.

I can see the `UIWebView` size as proper but the content is somehow dangling.

For the case, I checked safari in iTouch, but for them its working pretty fine.

I dunno where is the issue. I am posting it after a brief search but could not get any help either.

If any you guys know how to fix this, it will be really helpful.

Cheers,

Manoj

Comment: Can you further describe what exactly the problem is, maybe with a screenshot? Does the same website load and rotate in MobileSafari correctly or does the problem also exist there?

Comment: Hi Pascal, may be i can give you again a clear picture of the issue, its something like when you open a page (eg. ebay.in) on your Uiwebview and zoom in & zoom out and then rotate it to landscape mode, there comes the issue as the content of UIwebview(means the page) is not loading with its proper size.

Answer (score 0):

If your application supports all 4 orientation then in info.plist create a key for Supported interface orientations.

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
   // Return YES for supported orientations
   return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
   //Also you can use this method

}
```

Comment: Hi raaz, thanks for your answer, but this is not my problem. May be i can give you again a clear picture of the issue, its something like when you open a page (eg. ebay.in) on your Uiwebview and zoom in & zoom out and then rotate it to landscape mode, there comes the issue as the content of UIwebview(means the page) is not loading with its proper size.

Comment: Hi Manoj, Can u explain a bit more or give some screen shot regarding your problem.